# mysql batch with formatted logfile

Tags: mysql, logging, batch-file

my aim is to start a scheduled job on a windows server that deletes datasets on a local mysql server, also installed on a windows server.

But I would not just delete data, I want to create a logfile.

With this command:

```
mysql -v -h localhost -u user --password=password -P 3307 --database=smydatabase -B --silent --skip-named-commands < query.sql > logging.txt
```

an the following sql-file "query.sql

```sql
select count(*) from table;
```

I get the following logfile:

```sql
--------------
select count(*) from table
--------------

4420101
```

=======================

My first Question is: can I susspress the query and the both lines above and below.

The final sql-file will contain abount 20 Lines of sql-commands. My preffered goal is to create a formated logfile like this:

```sql
Job started at <date>
Deleting <4420101> datasets in table <table>
4420101 rows affected
Deleting <22013> datasets in table <persons>
etc.
```

So I have to create lines of logfile with select-statements and variables. other lines like delete-statements should not appear in the logfile. is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Include --skip-column-names:

```
mysql -v -h localhost -u user --password=password -P 3307 --database=smydatabase -B --silent --skip-named-commands --skip-column-names < query.sql > logging.txt
```

Hope this would help.